# Can I mock only one method instead of every object?

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito

I do have question, about using mockito.
Let's assume I have following method chain which I need to mock.

`mockHeroFacade.getHero().getItems().getSword().getId()`, so what my tested method need to is only `Id` of `Sword` object.
Until know, whenever I had this kind of chain I had two different approaches.

1. Is to mock `@Mock HeroFacade mockHeroFacade` and `when(mockHeroFacade.getHero()).thenReturn(createFullHero())`, so what createFullHero is returning is full Hero object with Items object, which cointains Sword object which contains its ID. And this is ok, but if object would be bigger it would take some time
2. Is to mock every object seperatly not only `HeroFacade`.

As seen below

```
class TestHero {
    @Mock 
    HeroFacade mockHeroFacade;
    @Mock 
    Hero mockHero;
    @Mock 
    Items mockItems;
    @Mock 
    Sword mockSword;

    @Before
    public void setup(){
        when(mockHeroFacade.getHero()).thenReturn(mockHero);
        when(mockHero.getItems()).thenReturn(mockItems);
        when(mockItems.getSword()).thenReturn(mockSword);
        when(mockItems.getId()).thenReturn(100000);
    }
}
```

And this approach is also working, but still, could be bothersome, to write a lot of code.

And I am wondering if I could go on shortcut and do something like:
`when(mockHeroFacade.getHero().getItems().getSword().getId()).thenReturn(10000)`

Comment: Does any of those classes that you mocked depend on each other ? If you could provide the code for those mocked classes would be better to help you.

Comment: @PedroLuiz This is just sample snippet, it is not real code. And the chain tells you that `Hero` has field od type `Items`, and `Items` has field `Sword` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find out the answer.

It is possible to use `RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS`, which tells mockito to make deep mocks.

```
@Mock(answer = Answers.RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS)
private MockHeroFacade mockHeroFacade;
```

This enable you to make chain call.